# Как остановить поток при случайном зависании?

Tags: java

Задали задачу в универе. Есть несколько потоков, которые с некоторой вероятностью могут попасть в `while(true);`(рандом). Создать дополнительный поток, который проверяет не завис ли поток. если завис, то остановить его и запустить заново. 
Т.е. interrupt() использовать не смогу. Нормально ли будет использовать stop()?
Какие последствия могут быть?

---

Как уничтожить поток из другого потока?

Comment: Какой критерий определения, что поток завис? При попадании в цикл выставляется какой-то флаг, или необходимо установить timeout?

Comment: @Pavel Parshin, просто запускаем рандом и если выпало, к примеру, 0, то мы заходим в бесконечный цикл, иначе не заходим. Внутри цикла ничего нельзя писать.

Comment: Это понятно. Но как другой поток должен определить, что текущий находится в этом цикле, а не просто долго выполняется?

Comment: @Pavel Parshin Для этого я в коде этого потока отправляю сообщение, мол я не завис. А тот класс смотрит, чтобы время ожидания было не более 5 секунд(условие задачи)

Comment: Условие цикла менять можно?

Answer (score 1):

Заведи в каждом потоке переменную типа long и при запуске потока пиши в нее текущее время в количестве миллисекунд.

В потоке проверки проверяешь, если текущее время +5000 больше или равно времени запуска потока, убиваешь зависший поток и создаешь заново.

Comment: Это  то я понимаю, суть вопроса была в том, как убить поток

Comment: Думаю stop() вполне подойдет. Он был объявлен, как нежелательный и потенциально опасный, но в, в данной ситуации, ничего фатального не произойдет.